# Canvas visibility is set but still hidden

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, windows-store-apps

I am working on a simple windows store app that has a `canvas` where you are able to preview the image from the camera on the device. There is a button that enables and disables the preview as well. I was previously able to preview the `MediaCapture` output (camera output) but now that I am trying to implement a working toggle for that preview, I am running into some issues.

Basically, I now have the `Visibility` property of the canvas that holds the preview set to `Collapsed` in the constructor of the `Page` that holds it.

```
    public MediaCap()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        capturePreviewCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```

Then I have the button click handler for when the user taps the preview button:

```
    if (capturePreviewCanvas.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
    {
        capturePreviewCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        await mediaCaptureManager.StopPreviewAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        capturePreviewCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        capturePreviewCaptureElement.Source = mediaCaptureManager;
        await mediaCaptureManager.StartPreviewAsync();
    }
```

The issue is that even when I debug the code and see it setting the `Visibility` property of `capturePreviewCanvas` to `Visible`, the canvas never appears on the screen like it did before I defaulted it to `Collapsed` in the constructor.

Is there some UI refreshing that I need to do to get the canvas to be visible again?

Comment: How do you know if the Canvas is visible or not (vs the contents of the Canvas)? Try making it red or something obvious so you can determine if it is the Canvas that is your problem put if it is something else that is not appearing.